# Show decline reasons for declined flags on the Post Flag History page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

Now that we have specific reasons for declining flags, it would be helpful to see them on the flag history page for questions and answers.

Right now, looking up the specific decline reason requires going to the flagger's profile and looking at their flag history to find the record of the flag there.

Comment: The lack of input gives this a lonely look and may lead to the impression (incorrectly) that this is not a good idea.  Therefore, input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this happened at some point (or was always there and I never noticed).

To see the decline reason, go to the flagging summary page, each declined flag has it's reason written out in red after the flag.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in all cases. I recently answered a [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134935/185951) because it seems as if there are cases when the declined comment flag count is incremented, but there's no user-visible history for it. Without knowing the internals, it seems likely this is related to deleted questions or comments. However, if the related question/answer or comment is deleted, shouldn't the flag count be decremented in the same way that reputation is adjusted when posts are deleted?

Comment: @CodeGnome Comment flags are a bit different. They're not handled/counted the same way as flags on questions and answers and their handling isn't really tracked. Also, no flag counts are decremented when posts are removed.

Comment: Some declined flags do not have a written reason. These flags are declined by community through post reviewing.