# How do I see which comment flags have been declined?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, comment-flags, declined-flags

I have previously flagged a comment and the flag has been declined. I am perfectly happy for the flag to have been declined but I would like to know which comment it is so that I can possibly learn from it.

Is it possible somewhere in my profile to view this? If not, should it be possible?

Comment: Didn't you mean the flag was declined? Because your sentence (and title) are structured like this and it seems the comment was declined: *"A comment (I have previously flagged) has been declined."* or is it just me?

Comment: You are absolutely correct - I have updated the title and text.

Comment: This now happens as shown in [More informative flagging history for comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180377/more-informative-flagging-history-for-comments).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue: I have exactly one(!) declined comment flag, but I have no idea what comment it refers to, or why it was declined. Maybe it was a well-deserved declination, maybe I just hit the mouse at the wrong time and the moderators realized that, or maybe it was a legitimate use of the flag but the moderators made a judgment call and left the comment alone--who knows?

*Who knows?* That's the point. If the declined flag count is meant to be a useful feedback mechanism for users, I really think that it should be more informative.

I'm going to change this to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and see if we can make this statistic more useful to the SO community. What say you all?