# Show reasons for helpful flags on the Post History Flag page

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

We already have the reason for declined flags ([Show decline reasons for declined flags on the Post Flag History page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111827/show-decline-reasons-for-declined-flags-on-the-post-flag-history-page)) on the Post Flag History page. I would like to have these reasons for helpful ones as well. In my opinion there are valid reasons to write remarks in the mod comment field, for once to make it clear to other mods or my future self why I did what I did or didn't do right there in the Post Flag History. Furthermore, it would feel a bit more consistent with the same behavior for helpful and declined flags.

The latter have one line with the flag comment and one with the mod's *answer/remark*, for the helpful flags the second line is missing. I would like that second line with the mod's side of things directly on the post, no matter the state of the flag as a second line.

I just found out that it is there as a tool-tip on *"Helpful"* and *"Declined"*. Anyhow I'd prefer to have it as a separate line since it would offer the information at first glance. Furthermore, there seems to be some format issues with the tool-tip. 
For example, `We're looking at it` becomes `We&#39;re looking at it` (Thanks Rubio)